# What does (*(int *)&(w)) mean in c programming?

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I'm learning processes and in the following code snippet:

```
/* 
 * fork10 - Synchronizing with multiple children (wait)
 * Reaps children in arbitrary order
 * WIFEXITED and WEXITSTATUS to get info about terminated children
 */
void fork10()
{
    pid_t pid[N];
    int i, child_status;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    if ((pid[i] = fork()) == 0) {
        exit(100+i); /* Child */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { /* Parent */
        pid_t wpid = wait(&child_status);
        if (WIFEXITED(child_status))
            printf("Child %d terminated with exit status %d\n", wpid, WEXITSTATUS(child_status));
        else
            printf("Child %d terminate abnormally\n", wpid);
    }
}
```

when I trace `WIFEXITED` function definition this is what I've got:

```
#define WIFEXITED(x)    (_WSTATUS(x) == 0)
#define _WSTATUS(x) (_W_INT(x) & 0177)
#define _W_INT(w)   (*(int *)&(w))  /* convert union wait to int */
```

I have two questions:

1. Why use mask `0177` instead of `0b1111111`, I've seen it many times, what's the benefits of using octal number over other formats? Personally I find binary more intuitive.
2. What's the meaning of `(*(int *)&(w))`?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO `0177` is an obfuscated way to write `0x7F`.

Comment: Yep, octal is just sheer obfuscation. `127` is much more readable and `0x7F` is the most readable.

Comment: `0b1111111` isn't clear. Is that 6 ones? 7? One would have to spend time counting ones to know what `0b1111111` means. (I find `0x7F` clearest here: All but the most significant bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binary constants such as `0b1111111` are not defined by the C standard and were introduced as an extension by some C implementations somewhat late, so earlier code necessarily used octal and hexadecimal constants, and programmers became accustomed to them. Additionally, octal is more compact, and I can count the number of set bits in `0177` more easily than in `0b1111111`. One quickly becomes accustomed to knowing that `7` means three bits set.

In `(*(int *)&(w))`, `&(w)` takes the address of the object designated by `w`. Then `(int *)` converts that address from the type “pointer to type of w” to “pointer to int”. Then `*` dereferences that pointer, nominally producing an `int` value.

The intent is to access the first bytes of `w` as if they were an `int`, effectively getting the raw bits that are in `w` instead of interpreting it as a structure or whatever other type it is. This is called *aliasing*.

Aliasing in this way is not supported by the C standard, but many C implementations allow it, and the code you show appear to have been written specifically for such an implementation.

A supported way to get the raw bits of an object is to copy bytes individually, as with:

```
int b;
memcpy(&b, &w, sizeof b);
```

Although this looks like a function call, good compilers recognize it as a request to access the first bytes of `w` as if they were an `int` and optimize it. The result may be a single load instruction. However, wrapping this into a macro that produces the `int` as a value involves some complications, which I will leave for further discussion elsewhere. (You can ask a new question about that, if desired.)

Comment: "Aliasing in this way is not supported by the C standard" It is, assuming `w` is a union as indicated by the comment. C17 6.7.2.1/16 "A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members and vice versa." In addition, the rules for effective type make an exception too, C17 6.5/7: "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
the following types: - a type compatible with the effective type of the object ... - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members".

Comment: Note that even if wasn't allowed by standard, it's legit for compiler-specific libraries such as the one being examined here to rely on extensions specific to that compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 Why use mask 0177 instead of 0b1111111 ... ?

(This answer only addresses this portion of your question)

Because `0b1111111` is not a C integer constant per [**6.4.4.1 Integer constants**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1):

> **Syntax**
>
> 1
>
> ```
>       integer-constant:
>             decimal-constant integer-suffixopt
>             octal-constant integer-suffixopt
>             hexadecimal-constant integer-suffixopt
>       decimal-constant:
>             nonzero-digit
>             decimal-constant digit
>       octal-constant:
>             0
>             octal-constant octal-digit
>       hexadecimal-constant:
>             hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit
>             hexadecimal-constant hexadecimal-digit
>       hexadecimal-prefix: one of
>             0x   0X
>       nonzero-digit: one of
>             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>       octal-digit: one of
>             0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
>       hexadecimal-digit: one of
>             0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>             a   b   c   d   e   f
>             A   B   C   D   E   F
>       integer-suffix:
>             unsigned-suffix long-suffixopt
>             unsigned-suffix long-long-suffix
>             long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
>             long-long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
>       unsigned-suffix: one of
>             u   U
>       long-suffix: one of
>             l   L
>       long-long-suffix: one of
>             ll   LL
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2 An integer constant begins with a digit, but has no period or
>   exponent part. It may have a prefix that specifies its base and a
>   suffix that specifies its type.
>
> 3 A decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit and consists of a
>   sequence of decimal digits. An octal constant consists of the prefix 0
>   optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only. A
>   hexadecimal constant consists of the prefix 0x or 0X followed by a
>   sequence of the decimal digits and the letters a (or A) through f (or
>   F) with values 10 through 15 respectively.

By standard, C only supports decimal, octal, and hexadecimal integer constants.

Answer (score 1):

1. 1. It has the advantage of not requiring any extra symbols as digits (the hexadecimal system is base-16 and therefore needs six additional symbols beyond 0–9). It is also used for digital displays.
2. You are trying to convert it to integer pointer and referencing the value from it.

Answer (score 1):

About your first question: Binary literals are not officially part of the C standard (and are only part of C++ since C++14), hence using octal literals instead of using them can improve portability.

About your second question: `&w` takes the address of `w`, which is then converted to a pointer to an int (`(int*)&w`) which is dereferenced. What that effectively does is read memory from `w` as though `w` were an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

you should check this link it will help you to solve any question by using (Clockwise/Spiral Rule)

http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html?fbclid=IwAR3V_KR4VwO33UvbO4LgN3AIW_79QBWAR9qHO2KHyyJgEuIKiFQOQTCec5U

(*(int*)&(w)) firstly &w means address of w where & is address operator then
 (int *) means creating pointer to integer so ( till this step you have pointer which point to address of w) finally * before this pointer means (you accessed the value of w )